# how do I overlay text on an image background

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS

```
.newbody
{
    background-image:url('Images/CityofChicago.jpg');

    height:600px;
    width:1270px;
    position:relative;

}

.otherstuff
{

     position:absolute;
}
```

here is my HTML

```
   <div class="newbody">
      <!--  <img src="Images/CityofChicago.jpg" height="600px" width="1280px" class="image" alt=""/> -->
      some Text

      <div class="otherstuff">
      <ul>
        <li>One </li>
        <li>Two </li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: here is your CSS, here is your HTML ... where is your attempt at making it work yourself?

Comment: I have been trying ... I am not a front end person, I thought using background-image url was what I was supposed to do, I was hoping someone might steer me in the right direction. I apologize if you think I am looking for someone to do my work for me, I can assure you that is not the case

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, and what isn't working? You can use jsfiddle.net like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/evsMF/) to illustrate things in addition to including your code in the question.

Comment: this is exactly what I want, but my image is not showing up. it is in a folder "Images/CityofChicago.jpg"

Comment: Where is your .css relative to the image? Is your .css file in a separate folder?

Comment: yes css is in its own file, images are in its own file

Comment: Looks like it's your path to your image: http://jsfiddle.net/U88z6/

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks right, it is just a matter of getting the right path to your image. If your css is inline in your html document the location of the html document becomes the base, if your css is in a .css file then its location is the base. If your structure is:

- index.html

  - /css

    - style.css
  - /images

    - CityofChicago.jpg

then the line would be `background-image:url('../Images/CityofChicago.jpg');`

Comment: you guys are all correct, but for some reason the line background-image:url('../Images/CityofChicago.jpg'); is still not showing the image. and the folder structure is exactly what you have shown above.

Comment: When you uncomment the image in html file does it display? What does the link to load the .css look like?